# Can't point saxParser to file directory

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

In my Eclipse project, I'm trying to parse an xml file into a String List to display in a jsp file.

My parser works perfectly with this code:

```
public class XMLReader{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(getXML());
    }
    public static String getXML(){
        try{
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLHandler handler = new XMLHandler(); // class I created extending DefaultHandler
           saxParser.parse("file.xml",handler);
           urls = handler.getXMLList();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return urls.toString();
    }
}
```

The string list is printed to my console as desired.
But when I try to rewrite the methods to return a string so that I can use it in my jsp file:

```
public class XMLReader{
    public String returnXML(){
        return getXML().toString();
    }
    public List<String> getXML(){
        ...
    }
}
```

I receive a java.io.FileNotFoundException.  In my console, it shows that Eclipse is trying to find the file in the folder containing my eclipse.exe, rather than in my workspace folder.  I've been searching the Internet for a couple hours but I have no idea what's causing to look in a different folder.  I'm not sure if making the methods non-static or using a jsp file is causing the file path to change, but I'm only encountering this issue with my saxParser.parse(file,handler) line of code, and I have no clue how to fix it.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Your code says:
     catch(Excdeption e){
Hence your parser clearly doesn't work perfectly with this code. Please post the actual code.

Comment: @EvanKnowles Had a couple typos...thanks for noticing.  The parser does work with the code, it just stops working when I try to return a String rather than do a System.out.println.

Comment: Your code doesn't show the declaration for `file`, or how the file name is set. Those things might be important.

Comment: @ScottLeis good point.  I just have the file name as a string.  Edited to reflect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to specify the full path to the XML file.

If you're calling `SAXParser.parse(String,DefaultHandler)`, the Javadoc says the String is a URI, so for a local file it should be specified as `"file://drive/directory/file.xml"`, using forward-slashes as the directory separator regardless of platform.

Otherwise, you can create a File instance, which allows you to specify a file path in a platform-dependent way (e.g. using backslashes in Windows), and call `SAXParser.parse(File,DefaultHandler)`.

You may want to dynamically determine the location of your Eclipse workspace folder, if that's where the file is. I don't know how to do that but there should be a way.

One final suggestion: naming your class "XMLReader" may be a slightly risky ambiguity because there's a common interface with the same name (org.xml.sax.XMLReader).